# Can I define one repository class for all the entity classes which I have

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am working on an MVC 3 web application which contains around 15 entity model classes representing 15 DB tables, I am currently performing all the business logic in one model repository class which is called from all the controller classes I have. I am doing all my work in one repository to:-

1. avoid partial updates.
2. wrap all the modification (insert, update, delete) into one DB transaction.
3. to avoid defining repository class for each model object and creating UnitOFWork class to coordinate between all the repositories, which I find that it will complicate the code and add extra effort.

so will my approach of having one repository class suffer from problems such as performance, security, etc, or other problems that I should be aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you want. However you might end up with an unwieldy repository implementation. You say you want to avoid defining one repos class for each model object. That is another extreme I would not recommend. There is usually a better middle ground.

There is a book out there called Domain Driven Design. One of its recommendations is to try using "Aggregate Root" repositories. This is where you organize your entities into groups according to their relationships, and then create one repository for each group. The main entity in the repository is referred to as the "aggregate root" of the group, and has other entities "dangling off" of it.

For example, say you have an Order entity that has a collection of LineItem entities. You can really only access the line items through the order, so you don't need a separate LineItemRepository. You can query the Order, and eager or lazy load the line items. The Order may then have a navigation property to a CustomerAccount entity, which has a collection of PaymentProfile entities. Again, same pattern -- you just create a repos for the customer account, and never query for the PaymentProfile directly. Query for it through the CustomerAccount.

Also I know from one of your previous questions that you are using EF. EF manages transactions for you. Each time you call SaveChanges, EF will run it in a transaction. So #2 is not really a good reason to have 1 giant repository.

**Update**

As far as UnitOfWork, with good upfront design, you can manage UoW across repositories pretty easily. Each of our repositories has a UnitOfWork object (which basically wraps EF DbContext). None of our code constructs the object directly. Instead we use our Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control container (Microsoft Unity) to automatically construct a UoW each time a repository is constructed by a controller (again, using dependency injection).

By configuring the dependency lifetime to be one instance for each request we can be sure that, at least in our MVC project, each repository gets the same UoW instance (and therefore all repositories have the same DbContext instance).

```
<register type="IUnitOfWork" mapTo="CustomDbContext">
    <lifetime type="singleton-per-http-context" />
</register>
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you would use IoC on the repository?  I'm very familiar with IoC containers (ninject).  I'm just not exactly sure how you would inject MyDbContext into the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement generic repository. Check out this article, hope it can be of some help

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: thanks for the link , but this what i am trying to avoid as it will require huge amount of work to create a generic repositiry and a UnitOFWork class to cordinate between all the repositiries. BR